# How can I implement error reporting (submit log to remote server) in Python desktop application

Tags: python, logging, desktop-application, remote-debugging

I'm writing an installed desktop app that I would like users to try out. I'd like to launch a pre-alpha release and collect some feedback, especially to fix any uncaught exceptions that might be thrown. As the developer would like to know about in the first instant.

i.e. I would like the installed desktop app to automatically submit relevant log entries to a remote server such that I can inspect them and fix the error.

I've considered using cloud-based services (they provide a nice dashboard interface: this is ideal) like but they're not really what I need:

- [Airbrake.io](https://airbrake.io) — quite pricey, geared towards webapps and servers
- [Loggly](http://www.loggly.com) — has a forever free plan, but for servers only, based on syslog monitoring. I cannot expect users to install a syslog client as well as my application

Answer (score 1):

I have never done centralized logging over internet connections, but in a local network. I used the standard sockethandler: http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#sockethandler and it worked for me.

Other alternatives may be:

http://code.google.com/p/python-loggingserver/

https://papertrailapp.com/

http://pyfunc.blogspot.de/2013/08/centralized-logging-for-distributed.html

Also saving to a regular local log on crash may be a solution, and on the next startup of the app check if the log contains errors and send the log to your email.

Comment: I like the latter idea you suggested. That would probably work best. The I would just need to set up a SMTP server for this...